# In Javascript, how do I obtain a reference to an element in an array?

Tags: javascript, optimization, reference, bit-manipulation, micro-optimization

I have a piece of code like

```
if (A[i][j] === 1) 
   A[i][j] = 0;
else 
   A[i][j] = 1;
```

and I'm wondering how I can optimize it like

```
var elem = A[i][j]; // obviously A[i][j] is an R-value ... I want an L-value
if (elem === 1) 
   elem = 0;
else 
   elem = 1;
```

In addition, I'm wondering if there's a single operation that can perform the equivalent of toggling between `0` and `1`, the equivalent of

```
if (elem === 1) 
   elem = 0;
else 
   elem = 1;
```

Is there some fancy bitwise operation that can do it?

Comment: I'm worried about you, Dr. Knuth.

Comment: Anyway the direct answer to your question is that you can't - there's no way to create an alias for an object property. In C you can get the address of something and save that value in a pointer variable; there's nothing like that in JavaScript..

Comment: @Andreas If `A[i][j]` can be anything different to `0` or `1` then, this wouldn't work.

Comment: @VisioN He's asking explicitly for a "fancy bitwise operation" to toggle between 1 and 0. For me this is enough to assume the values will be 1 and 0. But you're absolutely right. If there can be other values than that it won't work.

Comment: what are the types and what are the values of `A[i][j]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @Andreas is a good optimization.  Turned into an answer for posterity:

`A[i][j] ^= 1;`

It only retrieves the value once and applies the result.  You still can't get a memory address (JS is reference only), but it limits the number of times you have to access it.

The Bitwise XOR has the nice effect of turning `0 -> 1` and `1 -> 0` when applied with a 1 mask.  By doing all the work in one op, you can get the fewest accesses possible.

Edit: As per the discussion, this solution *only* works when the array is filled with 0 / 1 values.

Comment: Please make a note in your answer following the [discussion in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151712/in-javascript-how-do-i-obtain-a-reference-to-an-element-in-an-array#comment54113329_33151712).

Comment: In regards to the inputs always being a 0 / 1?

Comment: Yes. It is far not clear that all values in the array are just `0` and `1`. If they are, this solution will definitely work, otherwise not.